# Monitoring scheduled tasks in marklogic server

Tags: monitoring, marklogic

We have scheduled tasks in Marklogic server and they write to logs (e.g. TaskServer_ErrorLog). I would like to know if it is possible to monitor these tasks or the logs in MarkLogic Monitoring Dashboard. Also can alert mails be configured from MarkLogic Monitoring Dashboard?

Comment: What are you looking to monitor? Whether they had executed successfully or had thrown errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring History provides some information about the Task Server in the [Servers](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/monitoring/history#id_36450) detail section.

There are charts for:

- Request Rate
- Latency
- Expanded Tree Cache Hit Rate
- Expanded Tree Cache Miss Rate
- Queue Size

If you are looking to monitor for errors in the *TaskServer_ErrorLog.txt*, there isn't anything available to configure email alerts from the Monitoring History dashboard.

Typically, that is something that is configured and managed by log aggregation and monitoring tools, such as Splunk, DataDog, etc.

The [/manage/v2/logs](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/REST/GET/manage/v2/logs) endpoint could also be used to look for certain events within the logs by applying the `filename`, `regex`, and even `start` and `end` dateTime ranges.

You can send an email using [`xdmp:email`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:email). So, if you wanted an email alert if there were an exception in the execution of the task, you could wrap the code in a try/catch statement and send an email from within the exception code. Or you could configure a separate task that uses [`xdmp:logfile-scan()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:logfile-scan) to scan the `TaskServer_ErrorLog.txt` looking for particular events (or absence of them) and then send an email alert.